# Python raw socket doesn't see outgoing data

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, raw-sockets

I use the following code to create a raw socket : http://pastebin.com/pmg9iKgG
As you can see, i want :

- all TCP received packet send from port 5555 of a server to my PC,
- all TCP send packets from my PC to port 5555 of a server.

The problem is : i'm only able to see incoming packets, not outgoing packets. This is quite annoying for a sniffer...

Could you help me with this?

I'm using Anaconda as python distro (3.6, x64), on windows 10. wireless (intel) or ethernet (through USB adapter cause slim laptop).

I've search the internet and i haven't seen any problem like that. Moreover, MSDN says that it should work in both way (outgoing and incoming) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> One common use of raw sockets are troubleshooting applications that need to examine IP packets and headers in detail. For example, a raw socket can be used with the SIO_RCVALL IOCTL to enable a socket to receive all IPv4 or IPv6 packets passing through a network interface. For more information, see the SIO_RCVALL reference.

I would appreciate any help with this )))

Just on thing : 
i bypass this line of code :

```
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

by :

```
host = "192.168.0.29"
```

cause it's not the right value (but that's not the problem, moreover the methode socket.getfqdn() does the job, but i didn't updated my script)

EDIT : it was the windows FW that caused this strange behaviour, by deactivating some filter, i was able to see all incoming and outgoing packets.